# Delete selected items from list box in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to delete selected items from my list, on button click.
This is my gui-generated code with logic for delete (please see $Button1.Add_Click method - line 31)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

 $Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
 $Form.ClientSize = '400,400'
 $Form.text = "Form"
 $Form.TopMost = $false

 $ListBox1 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
 $ListBox1.text = "listBox"
 $ListBox1.width = 156
 $ListBox1.height = 274
@('Ronaldo', 'Pele', 'Maradona', 'Zidan', 'Pepe') | ForEach-Object {[void] 
$ListBox1.Items.Add($_)}
$ListBox1.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12, 23)
$ListBox1.SelectionMode = "MultiExtended"

$Button1 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text = "button"
$Button1.width = 60
$Button1.height = 30
$Button1.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(197, 16)
$Button1.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($ListBox1, $Button1))

$Button1.Add_Click( {
    $items = $ListBox1.SelectedItems
    ForEach ($item in $items) {
        $ListBox1.Items.Remove($item)
    }
})

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

For some reason it deletes only first item in $items. Others are ignored.
Why?

Answer (score 2):

As this error message shows, you can't alter the array in middle of `foreach` loop:

```
List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified.
An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change.
```

You can use `while` loop and retrieve the `SelectedItems` again after each removal. The `[0]` refers to the first element of an array:

```
while($ListBox1.SelectedItems) {
        $ListBox1.Items.Remove($ListBox1.SelectedItems[0])
}
```